# Call java method on button click

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to call a method in Java by button onclick in JSP?

For example:

**Java:**

```
@UrlBinding("/Student/import.action")
public class StudentAction implements ActionBean {

  public void testMe() {
      //do something
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<stripes:form beanclass="com.example.action.StudentAction">
   <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="call testMe"/>
</stripes:form>
```

I read some posts on Internet that it could be done by Ajax/jQuery, but I couldn't understand how they do it. I just know  itshould be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST"
    url: 
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){

    })
})
```

is there any other way to do this, and if no, I would appreciate a simple explanation of how to do it with Ajax/JQuery.

Note: I don't want to use submit input or stripes:submit!

Comment: What about learning basics about Ajax, HTTP and JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `ActionBean` (which is a servlet deep down), you can bind an URL to it with `@UrlBinding` (as you already do). You just need to make a HTTP request to that URL using Ajax in the `'click'` event handler of the button.

So you could have this markup:

```
<stripes:form beanclass="com.example.action.TestMeActionBean">
    <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="testMe()"/>
</stripes:form>
<script>
function testMe () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'action/testMeAction',
        ...
    });
}
</script>
```

On the server side, you just need to create the handling action:

```
@UrlBinding("/action/testMeAction")
public TestMeActionBean implements ActionBean {
```

After this, you only need to write a handler method. For example, using your method declaration:

```
    @DefaultHandler
    public void testMe() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not call Java method, you have to write `Servlet` then call the `doGet()` or `doPost()`method of `Servlet` on form submission or using `ajax` call.  [refer this example](http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-servlet-jsp-web-application-integration-example-tutorial)

Comment: Writing a pure servlet, when using a *servlet framework* seems like a bad idea to me.